# Mirror API or Glassware - adding an app to contact list

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

How do I add an app to the user's contact list to be able to share things such as pictures or videos with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Glassware needs to create a Contact for the user once they have added your Glassware. They may later be used as a share target.

See https://developers.google.com/glass/contacts for general information about contacts and https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts for information about how to create contacts from your Glassware and manage the contacts your Glassware creates.

Once you create a contact, the user will be able to share with it fairly quickly, but they are also able to turn off that share contact from their MyGlass page or app.

Comment: Is each contact publicly displayed for everyone to find?

Comment: The contact is added only for each user who authorizes your Glassware. (I have updated my answer a bit to reflect this.)

Comment: Thanks this clarifies it quite a bit!